# Adding new tables to Database Visual Studio ASP MVC - Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I decided to add a table to an existing database, but after 'update-database', the table doesn't appear. The database was also created via code-first.

Comment: Have you created the migration for the new table? And is the table setup in your Context? We need more info and code samples. This question is way too vague.

Answer (score 0):

1) open `Package manager Console` and type : `enable-migrations`.

2) each time you want to apply changes to your table type: `add-migration M1`. notice that "M1" is a name and each time you have to enter different names.

3) enter `update-database` to apply changes.

i hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add table in your DB Context class

   ```
   public DBSet<YorTableName> Name {get;set;}
   ```
2. Enable migration if not done by using enable-migration command
3. Update-database to create the table

Just check the connection string for DB